# Bootstrap input field square corners bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Im in the process of building a website (using Bootstrap) with a registration form; when applying validation feedback divs, the right-hand corners of each input field appear squared instead of rounded like the left-hand side.

An example of this can be see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqVeoL

And below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Why does the following input field have rounded corners on the left but square corners on the right?
    <form>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control">
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          Pass!
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Fail!
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    This is only the case when specifying valid and invalid feedback divs...
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course the validation doesn't appear until 'is-valid' or 'is-invalid' is specified in the input class but even then, the right-hand corners remain squared.

Am I making a mistake somewhere or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The [`input-group`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) is meant to have a button/add-on to the right. For a simple input, just use `form-group`...

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control">
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Pass!
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Fail!
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/o9HXbU3VpC